# Accommodation search in Italian Alps

Tags: accommodation, italy, alps

Is there a server that aggregates accommodation offers (not necessarily only) for the Italian Alps? I mean something like Tiscover (which is mostly Austria focused and has very few offers for Italy). Since I am a bit on budget the server should allow to sort by price within a reasonable radius around destination (like Tiscover can).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the classic websites like:
[AirBnB](https://www.airbnb.it/)
[Booking.com](http://www.booking.com/)
[Hostelworld](http://www.italian.hostelworld.com/)
[Associazione Italiana Alberghi per la Gioventù](http://aighostels.it/) (membership card needed, 2 euro yearly fee)

I don't know of others big aggregators for northern Italy. Many hotels and B&Bs have their own website with prices published there, so you can try a Google search with *hotel + name of the place* where you want to stay.

If you plan to stay more than a week in the same place, maybe a tourist accomodation would be better.
[Media Vacanze](http://www.mediavacanze.com/)
Prices start from about 300 - 350 euro per week, I don't know if it fits with your budget.

Comment: AirBNB and some other sites allow doing your search by map.  Consider also http://BeWelcome.org and http://WarmShowers.org